# windows 8 start screen default background image origin and meaning

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

Anyone can share the meaning and origin place of the windows 8 default start screen background image? What is the tower used for? the place is real or fake? Why choose such an image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research, it seems that the location depicted in the default Windows 8 lock screen (called img101.png in Windows 8.1) is Seattle, Washington. The tower you see is called the Space Needle, and it is an observation tower. That is, people go up into it for the view (and other embedded attractions at the top). I assume that the picture was chosen because Microsoft was formerly based in Seattle (and is still based in Washington, albeit in Redmond now). Whether or not the landscape is accurate is questionable. However, the tower, arches, and "skyline" all appear to match Seattle.